# How to keep justify paragraph in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Even though I have already `Ctrl + A` and `Justify (Ctrl + J)`, it will still be the default `Align Left` when a new paragraph is copied to the document. Is there a way to set the default as `Justify`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to either modify your default formatting style as such, or if your are pasting into an already formatted space then try the other Special Paste options (such as Match / Merge Destination Formatting or Paste as Text-Only).  FYI, you can also define a shortcut/hotkey that applies a formatting style.

Comment: How to modify the default formatting style as such?   I actually paste the text from the txt file, so is it text only?

Comment: @lanselibai There are multiple ways, but the easiest way in my opinion is to have it formatted as you want first, then highlight the block of text and go to Home > Styles > Create Style or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>.  You may want to extend more than one line and paragraph, so you capture the correct spacing and formatting for those as well without needing to configure in-prompt.  As for your paste default behavior, that purely depends on your settings for both your user as well as the specific document (can set global as well as doc-specific settings).

Comment: but, you can always 1) copy, then paste through context menu's Paste Options to select one yourself, or 2) paste and then (before any additional subsequent inputs) click the auto-format pop-up icon (or hit Ctrl), then select the desired type.  If you ever mess up, just use Ctrl + Z to undo, then immediately paste again and it should be all good!